# autofill the textboxes based on value selected in the dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title>Policy Creations</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* function autofillValues(country,state, city, pincode,branch,addrLine1,addrLine2){ */        
           function autofillValues(country){

        console.log(country);
           document.getElementById('country').value = country;
           alert(document.getElementById('country').value);
           /* document.getElementById('state').value = state;
           document.getElementById('city').value = city;
           document.getElementById('pincode').value = pincode;
           document.getElementById('branch').value = branch;
           document.getElementById('addrLine1').value = addrLine1;
           document.getElementById('addrLine2').value = addrLine2;  */
       }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1># Policy Creation</h1>
<br>
<h2>Insurer Details</h2>
<form name="newPolicy" th:object="${insurerList}">
Insurer Name<sup>*</sup>
    <!-- onchange = "autofillValues()" -->

   <select  onchange = "autofillValues('${insurerList')" >
     <option  value="">Select</option>
    <option th:each = "insurer : ${insurerList}"
            th:value = "${insurer.name}"
            th:utext="${insurer.name}" />     
    </select>   



Country<sup>*</sup> <input type="text" name="country" id="country"/>
State<sup>*</sup> <input type="text" name="state" id="state" value=""> <br><br>
City<sup>*</sup> <input type="text" name="city" id="city" value="">
Pincode<sup>*</sup> <input type="text" name="pincode" id="pincode" value="">
Branch<sup>*</sup> <input type="text" name="branch" id="branch" value="">
Address Line 1<sup>*</sup> <input type="text" name="addrLine1" id="addrLine1" value="">
Address Line 2 <sup>*</sup> <input type="text" name="addrLine2" id="addrLine2" value="">
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

i have a requirement in project where the dropdown is to be shown to the user. data to be shown in the dropdown list comes from database and is set in an object. this object is then iterated to show the dropdown..
in my case the object is an arraylist (insurerList)..
after showing the data in dropdown i then want to autofill the other textboxes whose values are present in the insurerlist object...

can anyone tell me how can i achieve this functionality in html?

iam using spring mvc....the value of insurerList is set in spring mvc's model attribute...
anyother approach to this problem are also welcome...

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead

```
<select onChange = "autofillValues('${insurer}', this.value)">
 <option  value="">Select</option>
 <option th:each = "insurer : ${insurerList}"
        th:value = "${insurer.name}"
        th:utext="${insurer.name}"/>     
</select>
```

The selected value and insurer array will be passed to the function `autofillValues()`.

```
function autofillValues(insurer, name){
  //get index of the selected name in the array
  var i = insurer.map(function (d) { return d['name']; }).indexOf(name);
  document.getElementById('country').value = insurer[i].country;
  document.getElementById('state').value = insurer[i].state;
  document.getElementById('city').value = insurer[i].city;
  document.getElementById('pincode').value = insurer[i].pincode;
  document.getElementById('branch').value = insurer[i].branch;
  document.getElementById('addrLine1').value = insurer[i].addrLine1;
  document.getElementById('addrLine2').value = insurer[i].addrLine2;
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: onchange inside the option does not work...the serve does not start..html cannot be parsed

Comment: @tin_tin, I have edited the code above. Take a look once

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to achieve this is to store your extracted data into an array, then autofill that data into the inputs you have created.

Check this code;

```js
   // Store the data in an array like the one below
   var values = ['Coder', 'Somalia', 'Puntland', 'Galkayo', '291', '2', 's-999', 'f-991'];  
   function autofillValues(insurer, name){
  document.getElementById('country').value = values[0];
  document.getElementById('state').value = values[1];
  document.getElementById('city').value = values[2];
  document.getElementById('pincode').value = values[3];
  document.getElementById('branch').value = values[4];
  document.getElementById('addrLine1').value = values[5];
  document.getElementById('addrLine2').value = values[6];
  alert('done!');
}
```

```html
<h1># Policy Creation</h1>
<br>
<h2>Insurer Details</h2>
<form name="newPolicy" th:object="${insurerList}">
Insurer Name<sup>*</sup>
    <!-- onchange = "autofillValues()" -->

   <select  onchange = "autofillValues('${insurerList')" >
     <option  value="">Select</option>
    <option th:each = "insurer : ${insurerList}"
        th:value = "${insurer.name}"
        th:utext="${insurer.name}" >  Click Here </option>       
    </select>   



Country<sup>*</sup> <input type="text" name="country" id="country"/>
State<sup>*</sup> <input type="text" name="state" id="state" value=""> <br><br>
City<sup>*</sup> <input type="text" name="city" id="city" value="">
Pincode<sup>*</sup> <input type="text" name="pincode" id="pincode" value="">
Branch<sup>*</sup> <input type="text" name="branch" id="branch" value="">
Address Line 1<sup>*</sup> <input type="text" name="addrLine1" id="addrLine1" value="">
Address Line 2 <sup>*</sup> <input type="text" name="addrLine2" id="addrLine2" value="">
</form>
```

Comment: i was thinking something similar..but the values to be filled come from insurerlist object which is defined..insurerlist is a list of objects..values to be filled come from the object..can u suggest a scheme to fill the array...i will try some combination when i go to office.

Comment: @tin_tin you can convert the insurerlist object to a text when you get it from your server. Then you can convert that text to an array using a regular expression.  After that you can execute the above code.